# Android Keyboard showing resize activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, keyboard

I'm trying to resize my activity when EditText become first responder and keyboard is showing.

For now I have used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. It works great but when keyboard is showing I can see the previous activity in the background. Is that normal?

Both activities have white background so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?

My second activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:background="@color/HWMMainColor"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="6dip"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: `see previous activity in background`..could you please elaborate..

Comment: I mean that the previous activity is visible. The current is resized but during keyboard animation, I can see the previous UI (difficult to explain and i can't attach a screenshot in stackoverflow) .. But when the keyboard has shown completely, we can't see the previous activity.